# CSS Content property doesn't work in MSIE?

Tags: html, css

Here (link removed) I'm trying to replace the text in an anchor with an image, using the CSS content property. I'm guessing that it's irregular behaviour for Chrome to do what I want it to do, by replacing the text with the image I provide in the CSS code?

Here's the code I use:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<a href="http://www.pegi.info/en/index/global_id/505/?searchString=Assassin%E2%80%99s+Creed%C2%AE+III&submit=Search#searchresults" class="pegi18">PEGI Rating</a> 

<!-- CSS -->
.pegi18 {
content: url("http://example.com/path/path/path/18.png");
width: 50px;
height: 61px;
}
```

Here's the end result in MSIE 11 and Chrome 32
[image: Internet Explorer vs Chrome]

Why won't the images show in MSIE? I've also done tests on modern.ie.

Comment: All versions of IE? Please be specific.

Comment: I tried your site in FF, doesn't work there either.   Is this a Chrome specific setting?

Comment: to replace content this way is a bad practice in my own opinion, chrome had this behavior since ever. content should only be used with pseudo-element ...

Comment: @Diodeus All versions, as tested on modern.ie, on WinXP, 7 and 8.1.

Comment: @Charlie74 I didn't have FF to test it, but that makes me think the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with GCYrillus, I too think it is bad practice and may not work in all browsers (as your post suggests). If you want to control the picture based on a class try adding a background picture instead of the content property.

```
.pegi18 {
background: url("http://daylostar.com/img/gwt/pegi/18.png");
width: 50px;
height: 61px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for also providing a solution. I had thought about that, but I used it as a quickfix.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why this isn't working is because css `content` is meant for pseduo-elements like `:after` and `:before`

Answer (score 2):

According to MDN,

> The content CSS property is used with the ::before and ::after
>   pseudo-elements to generate content in an element.

In your case, this doesn't apply, so it really shouldn't work in any browser (Chrome appears to allow it, even though it doesn't meet the specs)

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content

Answer (score 0):

According to [the CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-content):

> *Applies to:* :before and :after pseudo-elements

It looks like Chrome is going against the specification by allowing this property directly on an element instead of a `:before` or `:after` pseudo-element. For compatibility with other browsers, I'd recommend trying an alternative method such as using the `<img>` element or the `background-image` CSS property.